# Zip content without preserving folder structure

Tags: msbuild

I'm working on custom msbuild script.
One of the Targets should zip up build output.
For the sake of example let's say here's the path to output

```
C
-Folder
-------bin
----------Debug
```

I have following MsBuild target

```
    <Target Name="ZipFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
          <Binaries Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Folder\bin\Debug\**" />
        </ItemGroup>   

        <MakeDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Output"
                 Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Output')" />

        <Zip Files="@(Binaries)"
             WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Output\"
             ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Output\MyItems.zip"
             ZipLevel="9" />
    </Target>
```

I'm using `**` wildcard to select the content that is under `Debug`. I may have some folder structure with content files down the path, which needs to be preserved.

So for example, there might be `Resources` folder under `Debug` which would contain some `.txt` files. These should be zipped preserving the structure, so that final .zip archive file would contain `Resources` folder with it's content .

Script I have creates a MyItem.zip file with preserved full folder structure, so I end up with following in the .zip file

```
Folder
------bin
---------Debug
--------------Contents
```

What I want to achieve is to have contents of Debug in the .zip file **without** preserving folder structure up until Debug (excluding).
So I wish to end up with .zip file with following

```
    MyItem.zip
    ----------Content Folders (for example Resources)
    -------------------------Content Files
    ----------Files
```

Is there any elegant way to do it ?

I would prefer to not use any custom PowerShell scripts and if possible do it with what MsBuild + Community Tasks offer.

Comment: From the documentation: "The working directory is the base of the zip file. All files will be made relative from the working directory." Sounds like your problem? Try leaving working directory out, or set it to `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Folder\bin\Debug`

Comment: @stijn that's the case! Thank you, works like a charm! Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [source](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Zip.cs) which serves well as documentation for the community tasks:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the working directory for the zip file.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The working directory.</value>
/// <remarks>
/// The working directory is the base of the zip file.  
/// All files will be made relative from the working directory.
/// </remarks>
public string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }
```

So if you specify the workingdirectory it will be used to determine the 'starting point' for the content and in your case should be

`$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Folder\bin\Debug`